# shell script looping through some files in direcctory

Tags: bash, shell, file, unix

I have a directory full of csv files, and during runtime I will be generating some intermediate csv files. I would like to only iterate over the original files, and not the ones generated during runtime. The original ones start with "2017", so I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
for FILE in "$data_dir"2017*_"$i".csv;
```

where $i comes from iterating through an array of potential strings in this filename. However, even though I would like the results to be:

20170301_file1.csv
20170301_file2.csv
20170301_file3.csv
20170302_file1.csv

etc, an `echo` on `$FILE` returns:

```
2017*_file1.csv
2017*_file2.csv
2017*_file3.csv
```

I am not sure how to change the `2017*` part of my *for* statement.

Comment: Seems like the simplest thing to do is to use separate directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax could be as following...

```
for File in "${data_dir}2017*_${i}.csv"
do
# some commands...
done
```

You just need to quote the hole file and `bash` will handle the WildCard `*`,
I also added curly braces `{ }` to get the variables seperated from the rest.

Comment: Honestly, i don't understand how this could work for the OP's question, e.g. _I would like to only iterate over the original files_ -  but he accepted it - so... i must not understand to everything. ;)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: my concern was that I did not want the iterator to go over the intermediate files I create at runtime (what's happening in the # some commands part of suleiman's answer), but stick to the original ones, the ones starting with "2017". This method does what I want.

Comment: @suleiman: Why does quoting the whole expression including the wildcard solve the problem? I would expect the opposite. For instance if I do a `for f in "$HOME"/*`, the loop body is invoked once for each non-hidden entry in my HOME, but when I do a `for f in "$HOME/*"`, the loop body is invoked only once, because the quotes inhibit the expansion of the glob character.

Comment: thats why I use curly braces. Its always better to quote variables or in this case quoting the file. Without quotes and curly braces the behavior of the sript differs